# Changing the order of Facebook Open Graph actions in the auth dialog

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-authentication

Is it possible to select which Facebook Open Graph actions show up on the auth dialog? It defaults to alphabetical and only shows the first two. Our website has 4 actions and our more prominent ones are not showing by default. Could not find a way in the developer settings to change this order. Just seeing if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, you can't configure it in that much detail